# operator overloading "+" for types complex/double

Tags: c++

I put only the useful information in Complex.cpp.

Here is my problem: I made the class complex which means it can calculate in complex.
In the `+` operator I want to enable complex + double, but I can only use complex + double in `main.cpp`. When I use a double variable + complex there is an error. Why is that? Can I fix it?

#### Complex.h

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H
using namespace std;
class Complex
{
public:
    Complex( double = 0.0, double = 0.0 ); // constructor
    Complex operator+( const Complex & ) const; // addition
    Complex operator-( const Complex & ) const; // subtraction
    Complex operator*( const Complex & ) const; // mul
    bool operator==( const Complex & ) const;
    bool operator!=( const Complex & ) const;
    friend ostream &operator<<( ostream & , const Complex& ); 
    friend istream &operator>>( istream & , Complex& );
    Complex operator+( const double & ) const;
    //Complex &operator+( const double & ) const;
    void print() const; // output
private:
    double real; // real part
    double imaginary; // imaginary part
}; // end class Complex

#endif
```

#### Complex.cpp

```
Complex Complex::operator+( const Complex &operand2 ) const
{
    return Complex( real + operand2.real,imaginary + operand2.imaginary );
} // end function operator+

Complex Complex::operator+(const double &operand2) const
{
    return Complex( real + operand2 , this->imaginary );
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
int main()
{
Complex x;
Complex y( 4.3, 8.2 );
Complex z( 3.3, 1.1 );

    double ss = 5;
    x = z + ss;
    x = ss + z;//this syntax is illegal
```

Comment: I assume it's an exercise, because if not, there's already a class for complex in std::complex. include <complex>

Comment: it is an exercise , and thank you for your information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to allow your class to appear as the right hand operand, the operator needs to be a non-member. Since (in this case) it needs access to the private members, it will have to be a friend:

```
class Complex {
    // ...
    friend Complex operator+(double lhs, const Complex & rhs);
};

Complex operator+(double lhs, const Complex & rhs) {
    return Complex(lhs+rhs.real, rhs.imaginary);
}
```

Alternatively, as you already have a member taking the arguments the other way round, and addition is symmetric, you could define a non-member, non-friend function:

```
Complex operator+(double lhs, const Complex& rhs) {
    return rhs + lhs;
}
```

Comment: OK so I should make it a friend function in .h 
and Complex operator+ instead of Complex Complex::operator+?

Comment: Thank you so much I add friend Complex operator+(double lhs , const Complex &rhs); into my Complex.h and it works by the way are lhs and rhs key words

Comment: @user1923431: No, they're not keywords, just the names I usually use for the left- and right-hand side of an operator. You can call them anything you like.

Answer (score 2):

`operator+` is essentially a function. `x = ss + z;` is similar to `x = ss.operator(z);` But `ss` is `double`, it doesn't have `operator+` defined inside. You need to define an out-of-class `operator+`.
You can do it with the assistance of `friend` like suggested in other answers, but it would probably be cleaner without:

```
Complex operator+(const double& x, const Complex& c)
{
    return (c + x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use friend functions in this case.

```
friend Complex operator+( const Complex&, const double & );
friend Complex operator+( const double&, const Complex&);
friend Complex operator+( const Complex&, const Complex&);
```

Simple example:
http://liveworkspace.org/code/A14xS$0

Comment: I suppose there's still something else

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use a `friend` function. Add the following declaration to your class

`friend Complex operator+(const double&, const Complex&)`

Note that this is not a member function of the class, therefore the implementation should be as follows:

```
Complex operator+(const double& x, const Complex& c)
{
    return Complex(c.real + x, c.imaginary);
}
```

Comment: so you mean by this operator+(const double& x, const Complex& c)

Comment: computer will do as return Complex(c.real + x, c.imaginary);
when "+" is between a double and a complex?

Answer (score 0):

When defining operators, you should always provide complete sets. For `operator+`, this also includes `operator+=`, as a user would assume that if `cmpl = cmpl + 1.2` works, then `cmpl += 1.2` should also work. You can even use helper libraries like [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) or, if C++11 is allowed, my [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/) to simplify the code. For `operator+`, your code would be:

```
#include <df/operators.hpp>

class Complex
  : df::commutative_addable< Complex >,
    df::commutative_addable< Complex, double >
{
public:
    Complex( double = 0.0, double = 0.0 ); // constructor
    Complex& operator+=( const Complex & ); // addition
    Complex& operator+=( const double & );

    // I skipped the rest...
};
```

which will automatically provide the necessary versions of `operator+`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a member function `operator+=(const Complex&)`, and a non-member function `operator+(const Complex&, const Complex)` that uses `operator+=` to do the math. The non-member function does not have to be a friend. This is the usual pattern for this kind of thing.