# Qt overloading operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i'm trying write a polynomial class that can be used for calculation.

```
class Polynomial
{
public:
 Polynomial(QString s); // creates  a polynomial with QRegExp
 const Polynomial operator+(Polynomial const& rhs); // NOT TESTED
    const Polynomial operator+(double d);
    const Polynomial operator-(Polynomial const& rhs); //
    const Polynomial operator-(double d);
    const Polynomial operator-();
    private:
    void resizeToMin();
    QList<int> exp;
    QList<double> coeff;
    QChar var;
};
```

i would want to use the Polynomial like this:

```
 Polynomial p("3*x^2 + x^1 -1");
 double a = 2.0;
 p = p*2 // this works
 p = p*a // this works
 p = 2*p // DOES NOT WORK
 p = a*p // DOES NOT WORK
```

same for + and -

is this even possible? it would allow me to calculate with polynomials in the same way as with doubles

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clean your question up a little bit.  I assume it should be Polynomial p("3*x^2 + x^1 -1");  And not Polynomial p(3*x^2 + x^1 -1); Also do you want  p = p*2 // this works or  p = p*a // this works???  Its hard to tell exactly what your asking

Comment: I think this should answer your question

[Binary Multiplacation Operator (StackOverflow)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354886/simple-c-how-to-overload-the-multiplication-operator-so-that-floatmyclass-an

Answer (score 1):

Your operators only go one direction as you have them defined. As your class stands, you have the left side always be a Polynomial which won't work for `double*Polynomial` wherein the double is on the left side.

Since multiplication of polynomials is commutative (I think that's the word...`a*b=b*a`), you can define an operator like this outside the class:

```
Polynomial operator+(const double& lhs, const Polynomial& rhs) {
    return rhs + lhs; //switch the operation so that the polynomial is on the left hand side
}
```

It will take in the double as the lefthand side and apply it as if it were the right hand side.

Adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15741776/1124529

The linked answer also explains a little about doing operations if the operation is not commutative.